# regular expression in sed don't work

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed, data-manipulation

I've an samplefile like this

```
word1 ; word2 ; word3 ; word4 ; word5 ; word6 ; word7
word1 ; word2 ; word3 ; word4 ; word5 ; word6 ; word7
word1 ; word2 ; word3 ; word4 ; word5 ; word6 ; word7
word1 ; word2 ; word3 ; word4 ; word5 ; word6 ; word7
```

Now i want remove the blanks around  the ";". I have to work with sed.

the finalsolution

```
word1;word2;word3;word4;word5;word6;word7
word1;word2;word3;word4;word5;word6;word7
word1;word2;word3;word4;word5;word6;word7
word1;word2;word3;word4;word5;word6;word7
```

i used this statement and this works fine for the ";".

```
cat testdata.csv | sed -r 's/ ?; ?/;/g'
```

But in the first time i tried this way

```
cat testdata.csv | sed -r 's/( ;|; )/;/g'
```

and get this solution. It works for the field-end and not for the field-begin.

```
word1; word2; word3; word4; word5; word6; word7
word1; word2; word3; word4; word5; word6; word7
word1; word2; word3; word4; word5; word6; word7
word1; word2; word3; word4; word5; word6; word7
```

Is my sed-statement wrong or can't sed work with the "|" regular-expression?

Comment: If you say `sed -re 's/( ;|; )/;/g' file` it looks for the first pattern. I think the problem is that the two patterns have an intersection, so it either catches one or the other

Comment: i tried it so
sed -re 's/( ;)|(; )/;/g' and so
sed -re 's/( ;)|; )/;/g' but both ways don't work.

Comment: The Question for me is, works -r - Option for the regular expression correct

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the space followed by the semicolon is matching the first part of the pattern `( ;`, then sed continues to the next character, which is just a single space (so doesn't match either part of the pattern and isn't replaced).

One option would be to change your regular expression to this:

```
sed 's/ *; */;/g'
```

This consumes both the optional spaces in one go.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've matched the  `;`, the parser has already consumed the `;` and won't use it to match `;` .